# Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, debugging

e: {path}/Application.kt: (11, 51): Unresolved reference: setPluginRegistrant
e: {path}/Documents/User app and web/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/{path}/FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt: (15, 44): Unresolved reference: registerWith

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0):

1. Clicking on Gradle (on the right side bar) ->
2. Then under :app
3. Then choose assembleDebug (or assembleYourFlavor if you use flavors)